# Android, using resources of external jars

Tags: android, resources, jar, external

I'm working on a Android application and using this nice class to load a resource file, located in the applications res/raw folder, as a Java String:

```
public class ResourceReader {
    public static String resourceToString(Context context, int id) {
        try {
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(id);
            byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
            in_s.read(b);
            return new String(b);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The context is the Activity based application class, the id is found using R.raw.mytext. The resource is a file, created in the mentioned folder.
When used in the app, it is no problem to get the file's content as a string with this line:
String content = ResourceReader.resourceToString(this, R.raw.mytext);

As the resources I read are likely to be used in other applications, I would like to put not only the classes, but also the resources into an external JAR file.

In eclipse I can create an android jar file, complete with resources and associated R class. The integer values associated with the names are accessible as expected, but how do I read the content?

I need to get the resources of the library, not those of the application.

The resourceToString method needs a context:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
```

The Question is: is there a library context? And how do I get this context? - Or any other method to access the content of a library resource?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Android library. The output shall be an `arr` file which includes the classes and resources.

You may check [Create an Android library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) for details.

The following is an excerpt from that page:

> An Android library is structurally the same as an Android app module. It can include everything needed to build an app, including source code, resource files, and an Android manifest. However, instead of compiling into an APK that runs on a device, an Android library compiles into an Android Archive (AAR) file that you can use as a dependency for an Android app module. Unlike JAR files, AAR files can contain Android resources and a manifest file, which allows you to bundle in shared resources like layouts and drawables in addition to Java classes and methods.
>
> A library module is useful in the following situations:
>
> - When you're building multiple apps that use some of the same components, such as activities, services, or UI layouts.
> - When you're building an app that exists in multiple APK variations, such as a free and paid version and you need the same core components in both.
>
> In either case, simply move the files you want to reuse into a library module then add the library as a dependency for each app module.